# if then elseif then else then - statement in Angular 4

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3, angular2-directives

I have to apply one class from my 4 available classes (yellow, green red and white) to my **div** as per **status** condition in my angular 4 project.

```
<div *ngIf="item.status=='pending'; then yellow 
elseif item.status=='completed'; then green ... else white">
div content...
</div>
```

Only one conditions in above statement can be true.

how to achieve this (if elseif elseif ... else statements in angular4) ?

Comment: Use the ternary operator or an object.

Comment: use `ngClass` .. there are many overloads

Comment: can you explain more in answer section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

```
<div [ngClass]= { 
    'yellow-class' : item.status =='pending', 
    'green-class' : item.status == 'completed', 
    'white-class' : item.status != 'pending' && 'item.status' != 'completed' }>
</div>
```

Use [ngStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle)

In markup:

```
<div [style.color]=“getStatusColor(item.status)”>
</div>
```

or

```
<div [ngStyle]=“{color: getStatusColor(item.status)”>
</div>
```

In component:

```
getStatusColor(status) {
  switch (status) {
    case ‘pending’:
      return ‘yellow’;
    case ‘completed’:
      return green;
    default:
      return ‘white’;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If these are classes then you do not need *ngIf and instead need [`ngClass`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass).

Use it like

```
<div 
  ngClass="{yellow: item.status=='pending',
            green: item.status=='completed',
            white: item.status!='pending' && item.status!='completed'
           }"
>
...
</div>
```

Comment: its not working. while inspect i got this : <div ngclass="{yellow: item.status=='pending', green: item.status=='completed'}" class="{yellow: item.status=='pending', green: item.status=='completed'}" ng-reflect-ng-class="{yellow: item.status=='pending">...</div>

Answer (score 0):

You can also get class name from the back-end logic as below:

```
<div [ngClass]="GetClassName(item.status)">
    //div content...
</div>

GetClassName(status:string):string{
    let className:string='white';
    if(status=='pending')
    {
        className='green';
    }
    else if(status=='complete')
    {
        className='yellow';
    }
    .......


    return className;
}
```